# How to access standard eclipse icons

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, nattable

I am building a tree table using Nebula nattable and am trying to style it like a swt tree table. The issue now is I am trying to use the same icons for decorators as an swt table and can't find them.

The current icons are selected with the following:

```
 TreeImagePainter treeImagePainter =
                new TreeImagePainter(
                        false,
                        GUIHelper.getImage("right"), //$NON-NLS-1$
                        GUIHelper.getImage("right_down"), //$NON-NLS-1$
                        GUIHelper.getImage("leaf")); // This is an empty image acting as a placeholder to match the
                                                        // indentation
```

I would like to replace them with the icons shown in this image:
A is the desired icons, B is the current icons.
[image]

Is there a relativity easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These icons are coming from the operating system and afaik there is no easy way to access them. At least I have not yet found a way which is the reason for having those icons in NatTable itself.